# Reduce memory usage generated during excel creation - .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, openxml

I have a logic to create an excel from generic `List<T>`. The total records created are around 99700, but the problem is each time the excel generation method is called (with 10000 records), memory get shooting up (first iteration - 520 MB, second iteration 1G..etc) and it is not getting released. Below you can find the Excel creation logic that I have used.

```
try
{
    if (!filePath.Any())
    {
        return new UAOperationResult<string>
                    {
                        Content = "File path is empty",
                        Success = false,
                        Exceptions = new Exception("File path is empty")
                    };
    }

    using SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, isEditable: true);

    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();

    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();

    uint num = (uint)(sheetData.Elements<Row>().Count() + 1);

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (T record in records)
    {
         Row row = new Row
                    {
                        RowIndex = (UInt32Value)num
                    };

         if (columns.Any())
         {
             foreach (string column in columns)
             {
                 PropertyInfo propertyInfo = properties.FirstOrDefault((PropertyInfo x) => x.Name == column);
                 Cell newChild = new Cell
                            {
                                DataType = (EnumValue<CellValues>)CellValues.String,
                                CellValue = new CellValue(propertyInfo.GetValue(record)?.ToString()),
                                CellReference = (StringValue)(num + column)
                            };

                 row.AppendChild(newChild);
             }
         }
         else
         {
             PropertyInfo[] array = properties;

             foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo2 in array)
             {
                 Cell newChild2 = new Cell
                            {
                                DataType = (EnumValue<CellValues>)CellValues.String,
                                CellValue = new CellValue(propertyInfo2.GetValue(record)?.ToString()),
                                CellReference = (StringValue)(num + propertyInfo2.Name)
                            };

                 row.AppendChild(newChild2);
             }
         }

         sheetData.AppendChild(row);
         num++;
     }

     workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
     GC.Collect();

     return new UAOperationResult<string>
                {
                    Content = "file successfully created as " + filePath,
                    Success = true,
                    Exceptions = null
                };
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     return new UAOperationResult<string>
                {
                    Content = ex.Message,
                    Success = false,
                    Exceptions = ex
                };
 }
```

I am using `using` statement so I think GC will be applied directly. But for testing purpose I applied GC forcefully, but still the memory is not getting released.

Here is the snapshot of memory usage

[image]

By the end of execution memory reached around 3.7 GB.

Is there anyway to control this memory shoot-up ?

Note: I have also tried the logic using a `DataTable`. But still the issue persists.

Comment: I haven't test your code yet since you mentioned the records is huge, I just searched for the `SpreadsheetDocument Class` and found an example here, which had `spreadsheetDocument.Close(); ` after creating the spreadsheet. Could you pls take a look at [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument?view=openxml-2.8.1#examples) code and try if it helped?

Comment: @TinyWang .. thanks for the reply. But unfortunately it didn't make any difference in memory consumed.

Comment: yes, and I think this might be the expected behavior, will the code work well when the records is little? for example 100 records?

Comment: Yes , the memory consumption is proportional to number of records. So for lessor records it works fine. But the real problem is not the memory consumption, it is that even after excel generation , the server memory usage stays at the same level for long time. So which in turn affects the next request handled by the server.

Comment: Then can I understand as your requirement to be: force start the GC / release the memory?

Comment: I am sorry if I have confused you. I was looking for a solution which will release memory once the excel generation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if it doesn't make sense, I'm afraid this is the expected behavior. Just like you know, you had plenty of `new Rows` and `new Cell` because you had lots of records, and they would be released after the excel is created. During this process, the memory will cost more and more. We'd better to find a way which can divide the writing process into several parts so that the memory can be released in advance.

===================================

I did a test with code like below and as you can see the memory use didn't have a sharp increasment.

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string fileName = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\SpreadsheetDocumentEx.xlsx";

            // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the file name.  
            SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
                Create(fileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.  
            WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.  
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            // Add Sheets to the Workbook.  
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.  
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
                GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "mySheet"
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().FirstOrDefault();
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Row row = new Row();
                for (var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                {
                    Cell newChild = new Cell
                    {
                        DataType = (EnumValue<CellValues>)CellValues.String,
                        CellValue = new CellValue(j.ToString()),
                        CellReference = j.ToString()
                    };

                    row.AppendChild(newChild);
                }
                sheetData.AppendChild(row);
            }
            // Close the document.  
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            return View();
        }
```

Test result:

[image]